# Where is the predict() in Logistic Regression of Spark MLLIb implemented?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Can somebody point me to the implementation of predict() in LogisticRegressionModel of spark mllib? I could find a predictPoint() in the class LogisticRegressionModel, but where is predict()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `LogisticRegressionModel` extends [`GeneralizedLinearModel`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f85aa06464a10f5d1563302fd76465dded475a12/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala#L41) with [`ClassificationModel`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3cac6614a4fe60b1446bf704d0a35787d385fb86/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/ClassificationModel.scala#L32) (and some other less interesting stuff) it is reasonable to expect that `predict` is inherited from on of the above.

And as expected:

- [`predict(testData: RDD[Vector]): RDD[Double]`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f85aa06464a10f5d1563302fd76465dded475a12/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala#L63)
- [`def predict(testData: Vector): Double`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f85aa06464a10f5d1563302fd76465dded475a12/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala#L83)
- [`def predict(testData: JavaRDD[Vector]): JavaRDD[java.lang.Double]`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3cac6614a4fe60b1446bf704d0a35787d385fb86/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/ClassificationModel.scala#L57)